# Find strings with UPPER case letters and ends with a certain word in regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I have a dataframe where one column consists of strings that have three patterns:

1) Upper case letters only: `APPLE COMPANY`

2) Upper case letters and ends with the letters AS: `CAR COMPANY AS`

3) Upper and lower case letters: `John Smith`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['APPLE COMPANY', 'CAR COMPANY AS', 'John Smith']})

             NAME ...
0   APPLE COMPANY ...
1  CAR COMPANY AS ...
2      John Smith ...
3             ... ...
```

How can I take out those rows that do not meet the conditions of 2) and 3), i.e. 1)? In other words, how can I take out rows that only have UPPER case letters, does not end with `AS` or have both UPPER and LOWER letters in the string?

I came up with this:

```
df['NAME'].str.findall(r"(^[A-Z ':]+$)")
df['NAME'].str.findall('AS')
```

The first one extract strings with only upper letters, but second one only finds `AS`. If there are other methods than regex than I happy to try that as well.

Expected outcome is:

```
             NAME ...
1  CAR COMPANY AS ...
2      John Smith ...
3             ... ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can try:

```
df_new = df[~df['NAME'].str.isupper()|df['NAME'].str.endswith('AS')]
```

Answer (score 4):

one way would be,

```
df['temp']=df['NAME'].str.extract("(^[A-Z ':]+$)")
s1=df['temp']==df["NAME"]
s2=~df['NAME'].str.endswith('AS')

print(df.loc[~(s1&s2), 'NAME'])
```

O/P:

```
1    CAR COMPANY AS
2        John Smith
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work:

```
^(?:[A-Z ':]+ AS|.*[a-z].*)$
```

It matches either one of these:

- `[A-Z ':]+ AS` - The case of all uppercase letters followed by AS
- `.*[a-z].*` - The case of lowercase letters

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuvHaD/1)

Comment: Your answer is best :), for pandas based solution `df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.extract("(^(?:[A-Z ':]+ AS|.*[a-z].*)$)")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` and different patterns that you may want to check:

```
import re
def myfilter(x):
    patterns = ['[A-Z]*AS$','[A-Z][a-z]{1,}']
    for p in patterns:
        if len(re.findall(p, x.NAME)):
            return True
    return False

selector = df.apply(myfilter, axis=1)

filtered_df = df[selector]
```